# trouble understanding call-stack within a function

Tags: javascript, callstack

I currently am learning Javascript and C.S fundamentals, I am completing an assignment which was to create a function that takes a value(num) and outputs the index value within fibonacci numbers.

Example: function(6) outputs 8; because 8 is the 6th number in the fibonacci sequence.

fibonacci numbers: 1,1,2,3,5,8

index position: 1,2,3,4,5,6

below is the solution to the problem.

```
const fibonacci = function(count) {
  let a = 0;
  let b = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    const temp = b;
    b = a + b;
    a = temp;
  }
  return b;
};
```

The part I am having trouble understanding lies within the for-loop, from what I've gathered it seems this is how it's being executed within the call-stack:

1. execute b + a
2. store the previousValue of b in temp
3. a is now equal to temp/previousValue
4. execute b + a
5. update value of a...

but what I struggle to understand is why a stores the previousValue of B and NOT the currentValue.

When I envision the call-stack running I expected the output to look something like this;

```
0,1
1,1
2,2
```

instead of..

```
0,1
1,1
1,2
```

The value of a remains at 1 even though b is now equal to 2, after

```
temp = b;
b = 1;
a = 1;
b = a + b // 2;
a = temp;
```

a should be equal to 2 now, but instead it remains at 1; Why?

Comment: You are misusing the term "call stack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your misunderstanding is here:

> a is now equal to temp/previousValue

The value stored in `a` does not change until the last operation in the loop body. With the initial values of `a=0; b=1;`, when the loop body runs,

1. `temp` is set to the value of `b`, so `temp=1;`
2. `b` is set to `a+b`, so `b=1`
3. `a` is updated with the value in `temp`, so `a=1`

At the end of each loop, `b` holds the next Fibonacci value. The value in `a` is updated to the previous value only so that it can be used in the next iteration of the loop to calculate the new value of `b`.